# Beginner PHP Mail Function Issue + Server Error

Tags: php, html

So I'm a super beginner to PHP, but I'm currently building my first website and I wanted to have a contact form on the site that a user can fill out, and then have their information be sent to an email.

So I wrote the PHP for this using the "mail()" function, but for some reason whenever the user hits submit, it just goes to a page with the code on it and not the page I linked it to in the echo statement.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "rowan.krishnan@tufts.edu";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
$url = 'contact.html';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'  
?>
```

And here's my html:

```
<div id="emailform">
   <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
       Name: <input type="text" name="name">
       Email: <input type="text" name="email">
       Phone: <input type="text" name="phone">
       Message: <textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
       <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
   </form>
</div>
```

My final problem is related to the web server/host that I use (hostgator). For some reason, whenever I upload any documents that contain PHP in them, I get a 500 Internal Server Error and I'm not really sure what's going on there. If any of you know what I'm talking about, it would be great if you had advice.

Thanks so much for reading all this and helping out.

Comment: So the problem is with getting any PHP script to work, and has nothing to do with sending mail?

Comment: Well it's kind of two parts. First, I don't understand why my "echo" statement doesn't work and it just goes to a white page of PHP code when I try to run it locally. Secondly, my server is giving me an error whenever I try to access a page that has any PHP or links to a PHP file.

Comment: The first problem could be caused by the second: if the script isn't running, you won't get any echo.

Comment: But I'm only getting an error on my online server. Shouldn't I be able to run it locally without problems like that?

Comment: couple things - first, php is enabled on the server, right> - you should place your mail script in a conditional that executes only if the fields are populated. as is you could call it directly and send you empty emails. no need for the meta refresh. you can use header('location: contact.html'); instead. and also host gator is a joke. For the same price you can get real service from somewhere like media temple or dreamhost.

Comment: Yes it is saved as mail.php. And I'll add the conditional and use that "header" command instead. I didn't choose to use hostgator, I'm making this website for someone else so unfortunately I have to put up with it.

Comment: sorry - i updated my snide comment. can you verify php is enabled for your service? if the extension is php you should not see any code here. it should just forward you to contact.php. hostgator might only enable php by request.

Comment: I just checked and it says that hostgator is using at least PHP 5.2 or 5.3 for this account.

Comment: can you try adding a simple script that mails eg something from php.net that is hardcoded and see if that sends a mail and check your error logs

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` at the end of your echo which is most likely causing the white page

```
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
                                                           ^
```

try checking your errorlogs to see what errors you have been getting and try turning on error messages

also the message needs to have \r\n for each line

```
$formcontent="From: $name \r\n Phone: $phone \r\n Message: $message";
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't really fix it. Maybe I can't run the PHP script locally because I don't have a mail server installed on my computer?

Comment: sometimes you'll have to set up your mail parameters. I don't know how but you can search on SO or Google, but I don't think that would be causing your white page.

Comment: Well on the actual website it is showing the source code for hostgator's default 500 Internal Server Error page. On my computer I can just see the PHP code on a white page after I hit submit and the source code is the regular PHP I used.

Comment: @RowanK. it looks like you aren't accessing your localhost properly. you should  have a link like localhost/path/to/your/scripts/mail.php or 127.0.0.1 in stead of localhost

Comment: I'm guessing it won't work locally because I need to download some sort of server for my own computer like WampServer. The more serious problem is why it won't work online with hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run php locally, you need to first be running a web server that has php installed. Try xamp as it is really easy to install and get going and allows you to run your php locally. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

After generating your variables, a simple php email script will look like this.. (which you seem to have correct)

```
//Generate the email
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '. $senders_email;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

As Kai Qing mentioned, use `header('location: contact.html');` to redirect the page. echo simply prints to screen whatever you send it. 
A better approach is to use a callback function in your html document. So you would send the form using a javascript funciton for example, once the response is recieved (your email sent) a callback function would then do what you like, such as show a different page or print a confirmation message.

A jQuery approach would look something like this

```
//send form to order.php for further processing
var formData = $('#promo-form').serialize();
$.post('order.php',formData,formSent);
//formSent is the callback funciton
```

Your server 500 errors may be due to the permissions set on your php files. In your ftp client, check the permissions of the php files are set to 0644. Further information about this error can be found at:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/http-error-500-internal-server-for-php-pages-and-solution.html
- [500 error with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916763/500-error-with-codeigniter)
- http://x10hosting.com/forums/scripts-3rd-party-apps-programming/166905-phpmail-my-smtp-server-500-error-file-permissions.html
- https://www.bitrixsoft.com/support/training/course/?COURSE_ID=12&LESSON_ID=447

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<?php
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  This would be your mail.php file
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Lets Just Check Basic PHP Installation Is Working
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
if (!function_exists('mail')) {
    die('mail() is not available');
}
//
//
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Validate Required Passed Fields 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] !='' && isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !='' && isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] !='' && isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] !='' ) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
}
else
{
    die('Sadly you did not complete all of the fields on our contact form');
}
//
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Validate The Email... This Is Just An Example
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
if (preg_match('/^[-!#$%&\'*+\\.\/0-9=?A-Z^_`{|}~]+@([-0-9A-Z]+\.)+([0-9A-Z]){2,4}$/i', trim($email))) {
    die('Email Address Invalid. Please Check Your Email.');
}
//
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Build Your Email Message
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
$EmailMessage .= "Name: " . $name . " \n\n";
$EmailMessage .= "Email: " . $email . " \n\n";
$EmailMessage .= "Phone: " . $phone . " \n\n";
$EmailMessage .= "Message: " . $message . " \n\n";
//
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Build Email Header
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
$EmailHeader .= "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . "> \n";
$EmailHeader .= "Reply-To: " . $name . " <" . $email . "> \n";
$EmailHeader .= "Return-Path: " . $name . " <" . $email . "> \n"; // running a windows server??
//
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Send The Email & Confirm It Processed
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
if (mail('Rowan Krishnan <rowan.krishnan@tufts.edu>', 'Contact Form', $EmailMessage, $EmailHeader)) {
    //
    // it appears to have worked, so redirect somewhere else
    //
    header("Location: contact.php");
    die('Contact Form Redirect');
} else {
    echo('Contact Form Failed');
}
?>
```